# wget downloads .png files that are not viewable

Tags: windows, png, wget

I access my account and attempt to donwnload a list of .png files.

```
wget --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data "Username=----- &Password=-------" https://satwinds.windenergy.dtu.dk/User/Login

wget --load-cookies cookies.txt --input-file=PNG_list.txt
```

`PNG_list.txt` contains the urls for the .png files as below:

https://satwinds.windenergy.dtu.dk/SatelliteWinds/Download/S1B_ESA_2017_12_31_06_05_22_0568015522_2.40E_54.03N_VV_C11_GFS025CDF_wind.png

The files download but when I try and open them with Photoviewer or other image viewing software I get this error message

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjOu9.png]

This same method works for .nc files in the same folder - downloading openable files. Manual download of .png files from the website produces openable files. Using a list without '.png' extensions still downloads unopenable files.

Comment: Do they work if you download them manually?

Comment: Yep 'Manual download of .png files from the website produces openable files'

Comment: Compare the contents of a manually downloaded file against the same one downloaded with `wget`. That might tell you something more than Windows' meaasge "this does not work".

Comment: How do I compare the file contents of two .png files? Thanks